# Encontrar signo $ en el texto

Tags: c#, string, while

Tengo esto de tarea, pero no es como hacer la parte de que deje de leer si encuentra un signo de $.

Mi código

```
string texto;
string vocales;
int a1, a2, i;

Console.WriteLine("ingrese su texto");
texto = Console.ReadLine();

a1 = texto.Length;
a2 = 0;
i = 0;

while (i < texto.Length)

{
    if (texto[i] == 'a' || texto[i] == 'e' || texto[i] == 'i' || texto[i] == 'o' || texto[i] == 'u')
    {
        a2++;
    }
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine("la cantidad de caracteres es: " + a1);
Console.WriteLine("el numero de vocales es: " + a2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Probaste colocar un if (texto[i] == '$') break;  ????

Comment: Se puede usar el método String.Contains que verifica si existe un carácter en una cadena dada.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar la condición al while. Así:

```
while (i < texto.Length && texto[i] != '$')
{
    if (texto[i] == 'a' || texto[i] == 'e' || texto[i] == 'i' || texto[i] == 'o' || texto[i] == 'u')
    {
        a2++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

---

También puedes averiguar la posición del primer `$` en la cadena con [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) y recorrer solo hasta esa posición. Así:

```
int limite = texto.IndexOf('$');
if (limite < 0)
    limite = texto.Length;

while (i < limite)
{
    if (texto[i] == 'a' || texto[i] == 'e' || texto[i] == 'i' || texto[i] == 'o' || texto[i] == 'u')
    {
        a2++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

---

Por cierto, realmente no hay diferencia, pero con un for puedes expresarlo de forma más compacta:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.Length && texto[i] != '$'; i++){
    if (texto[i] == 'a' || texto[i] == 'e' || texto[i] == 'i' || texto[i] == 'o' || texto[i] == 'u')
    {
        a2++;
    }
}
```

Otra sugerencia: dale nombres descriptivos a tus variables. `a2` no te da mucha información. En cambio `vocales` o `nVocales` sí.

Answer (score 0):

@Mateo ya te lo respondió perfecto, pero quería enseñar otro enfoque del problema usando un poco de linq.
Codigo:

```
        string texto;
        string vocales;
        
      

        Console.WriteLine("ingrese su texto");
        texto = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!texto.Contains('$'))//pregunta hasta que tengamos un $
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese mas texto");
            texto += Console.ReadLine();//suma al texto ya obtenido
        }
        texto = texto.Split('$')[0];//parte el string en partes respecto el $ y coge el primero de las partes
        vocales = String.Concat(texto.Where(i => i.Equals('a') || i.Equals('e') || i.Equals('o') || i.Equals('i') || i.Equals('u')));//cojo las vocales con linq y las concateno en un string (se puedes hacer usando la array);
        Console.WriteLine(vocales);//enseña las vocales

      

        Console.WriteLine("la cantidad de caracteres es: " + texto.Count());//contador total
        Console.WriteLine("el numero de vocales es: " + vocales.Count());//contador de vocales
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]